# TSQL - Join text fields to one big text

Tags: t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
ID    text_1     text_2     text_3
12    some text  some more  even more
```

I need it to be put it to be put to one string so it comes out like

```
some text\n\nsome more\n\neven more
```

Now I know that \n is something else in TSQL but I can't remember what, maybe CHAR(13).

Anyone know to archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return the string you want:

```
SELECT text_1 + '\n\n' + text_2 + '\n\n' + text_3
FROM myTable
```

If you want a line break character you will indeed need to use `CHAR(13)` and for a line feed `CHAR(10)`, in a similar manner:

```
SELECT text_1 + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + text_2 + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + text_3
FROM myTable
```

As [@Adam Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82187/adam-robinson) comments, if the `text_x` fields are of type `TEXT` or `NTEXT` you will need to convert them first.

Comment: +1. Note that this won't work if the data type is actually `TEXT`. To do this, you'll have to `convert(varchar(max), text_1)` (etc.) first

Comment: It was the convert I was missing :)